# Hosted Pool Missing in Visual Studio Online in Build section

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ms-release-management

I am setting up Visual studio online Release management and I am referring this link

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-agent-pool

to select Hosted Pool Agent in Visual studio online.. But it is missing for me.. I am refering this link in order to solve the below issue

Please help

---

### Error

There are issues with the request or definition that will prevent the build from running:There are agents that are capable of running the build, but they are not online. If the agent is configured to run as a service, ensure that the "VSO Agent ({agent name})" service is running.The value specified for SourceVersion is not a valid commit id.

Answer (score 3):

VS online release management does not yet work with hosted pool. You need to setup your own agents for a few more weeks until that support comes in.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.. but if i am using VSO as a service do i still need to setup Agents for  Auto deploy ?

Comment: @user1037747 Per Vijay, the Release Management Service in VSO currently does not work with hosted agents. It will be coming in a future update. Until then, your only recourse is to set up an agent -- this can be in an Azure VM if you want to remove the need to manage on-premise infrastructure.